# Woocommerce PHP create Array of images with specific name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, image-gallery

I need to query all images in media library containing a certain string in the name.
For example i have Carpet_01_1.jpg  Carpet_01_2.jpg Carpet_01_3.jpg and store them ID(as suggested by martin-mirchev) in an array.
Than i will use that array to set product gallery based on the same string.

Thanks alot for any help!

Finally i got it working, there is still something odd because it echoes 5 times the same image if i do echo id or url, but it works ok if i print the image title, maybe something wrong in the way i use arrays?Here is the code:

```
   <?php
    $search_string="gunnar";
 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    's'=> $search_string,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);


$post_count = count ($attachments);

if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo "<div class=\"post photo col3\">";
    $url = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);  
    
    $img = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
    $attachment_id = get_the_ID( $url );
    echo $attachment_id;
    $title = get_the_title($attachment);
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><img title="'.$url.'"</a>';
    echo "</div>";
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not using image IDs  ? Since you already know the IDs... Otherwise you need to query post type attachments first find the images store them in array etc.. or use sql its pointless in my opinion all that work.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply!You mean, inside the loop, to query the id of images containing $product in the name?